# zsh - OSX - visual studio command line won't stick

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, zsh

```
which code
code not found
```

Selecting the `Install 'code' command in Path` option from the VSCode command palette only fixes the problem temporarily.

The code command works then, even when I restart the terminal.

However, when I restart my computer I am back to

```
code not found
```

I can see that code is at `/usr/local/bin/code`

`/usr/local/bin` is already in my path.

Comment: is `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH` before you launch Visual Studio?

Comment: Yep. I can always safely use the atom keyword for example, which is also in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 3):

Check that the symlink `/usr/bin/local/code` isn't pointing to a translocated version of the VSCode binary. Mine was.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/code
code -> /private/var/folders/hz/w...n/T/AppTranslocation/...
```

### To fix

1. Ensure your VSCode installation is not running in App Translocation. This can happen if you move the VSCode binary to `/Applications` by, for example, using an Alfred workflow. You must manually drag the binary in to the folder in Finder. (What a drag. Ha ha. But seriously, WTF Apple?)
2. You can fix this by dragging your existing binary out to the Desktop then back to the Applications folder.
3. Delete the broken symlink: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/code`.
4. Re-install the link using the command in VSCode ("Install 'code' command in PATH").